# Do declarative programming languages have statements?

Tags: programming-languages

Do declarative programming languages have statements?

Or, another way, are statements peculiar to imperative languages?

Comment: How do you define "statement" and "declarative programing language"?

Comment: @Marcin - they don't have well defined meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether I am 100% correct, but my understanding is the following:

**Imperative languages**, whether they are procedural (like C) or Object-Oriented (like Java or C++), perform a computation by containing many **assignment statements**, which mutate the variables to which they assign to, and as a direct result, **change the program's state**. This statement flow is controlled by what's known as control flow, which in a broad sense is the various conditional or unconditional jumps in the program (if statements, loops, etc).

**Declarative languages** on the other hand work widely different, especially depending on the subgenre of the language:

- For instance, **functional languages**, (such as Scheme and Haskell), have their programs written as a series of expressions, which get composed into functions. These functions are then applied to the input given to the program, and produce an output. In essence, it works like functions in the mathematical sense: **it maps a value from its domain to a value from its range**.
- **Logic or constraint-based languages**, such as Prolog for example, have their programs expressed as a sequence of *facts, rules or queries*, which are then processed by a (theorem proving like) engine.

Comment: Object-Oriented languages are not a subclass of Imperative languages. There are several Object-Oriented languages derived from Declarative languages, both functional and logic. From an encapsulation and reuse point-of-view, Object-Oriented concepts sit at higher level than imperative, functional, and logic concepts and can be applied, interpreted, in the context of most language paradigms.